# Tag Request: creature-size

Tags: support, tags

As I don't have enough rep to create tags yet, I'd like to request that 'creature-size' be added as a new tag.  A question that would have used it: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of allowing a player to play a large creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-allowing-a-player-to-play-a-large-cr)

Comment: Can you find more than one example that would have used it?  What benefit would it provide (ie: when would someone search on filter on `creature-size`)?

Comment: No, Not really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a pretty weak tag that won't get used much at all - I'd stick to more general tags in this case.

Comment: I think you're right about this.

Answer (score 3):

Disagree with @mxyzplk. Size is a technical term in D&D which has specific rules associated with it. It could be helpful to look up size-related rules. Here are a couple of questions for which the size tag could be appropriate:

[Why did D&D 4th Edition Remove the Size To-Hit Modifiers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8230/why-did-dd-4th-edition-remove-the-size-to-hit-modifiers)

[How much vertical space do a rider and mount occupy together?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/how-much-vertical-space-do-a-rider-and-mount-occupy-together)

[Do creatures occupy cubic space, or are larger creatures still one square tall?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/do-creatures-occupy-cubic-space-or-are-larger-creatures-still-one-square-tall)

[Close burst from a large creature -- one square origin or all of them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/close-burst-from-a-large-creature-one-square-origin-or-all-of-them)

[How do you rule halfling tossing as a combat action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-do-you-rule-halfling-tossing-as-a-combat-action)

Size is related, but not identical, to the 3d-space tag.

Comment: If it's very D&D specific then go with a D&D tag.  Or more specifically which version of D&D since the affects of creature size varies from edition to edition.  If this had a cross use between many systems it might possibly be useful but since each system will handle it different better to just tag it with the system.